# Combinations of a list of items in efficient way

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find if there is a more efficient way of finding these combinations using some Python scientific library.

I am trying to avoid native `for` loops and list append preferring to use some NumPy or similar functionality that in theory should be more efficient given it's using C code under the hood. I am struggling to find one, but to me this is quite a common problem to make these operations in an efficient way rather than using slow Python native structures.

I am wondering if I am looking in the wrong places? E.g. this does not seem to help here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html

See here I am taking the binomial coefficients of a list of length 5 starting from a lower bound of 2 and finding out all the possible combinations. Meanwhile I append to a global list so I then have a nice list of "taken items" from the original input list.

```py
import itertools

input_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

minimum_amount = 2

comb_list = []
for i in range(minimum_amount, len(input_list)):
    curr_list = input_list[:i+1]
    print(f"the current index is: {i}, the lists are: {curr_list}")
    curr_comb_list = list(itertools.combinations(curr_list, i))
    comb_list = comb_list + curr_comb_list
print(f"found {len(comb_list)} combinations (check on set length: {len(set(comb_list))})")
print(comb_list)
```

Gives:

```
found 12 combinations (check on set length: 12)
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), 
('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), 
('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'e')]
```

- Is it possible to do this avoiding the `for` loop and using some scientific libraries to do this quicker?
- How can I do this in a quicker way?

Answer (score 2):

The final list contains all combinations of any length from 1 to `len(input_list)`, which is actually the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). 
Look at [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements).

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant to have a "take 2" as a parameter like `minimum_amount`. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want all combinations from *input_list* of length *2* or more.

To get them, you can run:

```
comb_lst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    [ itertools.combinations(input_list, i)
        for i in range(2, len(input_list)) ]))
```

Something similiar to *powerset* in examples in the *itertools* web site,
but not exactly the same (the length starts from **2**, not from *1*).

Note also that *curr_list* in your code is actually used only for printing.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the code snippet using `curr_list` inside the `for` loop. The "take 2" is to be considered a parameter like `minimum_amount`.